# How to draw a repeated image, but constrain it to a 2D circle in Java?

Tags: java

How would you go about repeating a texture to fill a circle. To be specific: I am using a 5x5 .PNG as the thing or object that will fill the circle. I want to use that to fill my tetrain. At the moment I am having problems making the terrain where it will fill the circle, but rounded.

My specific problem with the generation is that it fills it, however it is not rounded because it goes all the way to the max y at all points. The x axis however is not a problem at the moment. My code right now for the generation of the terrain is so:

```
for(float x = mapEdge.getMinX() ; x < mapEdge.getMaxX() ;   x += 5 ){
            for(float y = mapEdge.getCenterY() ; y > mapEdge.getMinY(); ){
                y -=5;
                g.drawImage(grass,x, y);

        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is a bit too broad and doesn't fit well with the Q/A format of the site. This site isn't for discussion based questions like this one. Start smaller, get something that can generate blocks, then something that can make large areas of block with chunking. Then move on to making them in a circular shape. See the [FAQ] for some links on getting started and to learn what types of questions to ask here. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Graphics.setClip()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setClip%28java.awt.Shape%29) to set arbitrary clipping shape. After that all image drawing calls will be clipped inside this shape.

```
Shape oldClip = g.getClip();
g.setClip(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, diameter, diameter));
// Draw the images here
g.setClip(oldClip);
```

Comment: I am having problems finding the solution to the following error-The method setClip(Rectangle) in the type Graphics is not applicable for the arguments (Ellipse2D.Float)

Comment: Are you using Java ME or some other limited version of Java? This method has been in standard Java since version 1.1.

Comment: Eclipse Juno,latest version of java, and java EE. P.S. I am very new to programming so if none of those were the answer you were looking for please tell me, also i am using slick2D with lwjgl.

Comment: Slick2d has it's own Graphics class, which doesn't support arbitrary clipping shapes. From the documentation it seems that [Graphics.texture(Shape, Image)](http://www.slick2d.org/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Graphics.html#texture(org.newdawn.slick.geom.Shape,%20org.newdawn.slick.Image)) could do what you are looking for.